# Android Studio 3.1.3 Update Error

Tags: android-studio-3.1.3

I got this error when trying to update android studio 3.1.3:

[image: Error]

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar error.  The only solution I found was to uninstall my outdated Android Studio version (which wouldn't patch/upgrade) and then I went online and installed the latest/current Android Studio version.  No patching/upgrade would go through, so I just uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Comment: it's a good idea. do I need to install all the SDKs, when I install the new version?

Comment: No, your SDK/SDK-tools will still be there.  If you downloaded them to a non-default directory, you will have to point the new Android Studio installation to them.  Good luck!